# Maven install goal does not generate pom for modules

Tags: maven

I'm running a multi-module maven project and have an unexpected behavior. First time I'm seeing this...

My parent module configures the `install` plugin, defining its `classifier`.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                <classifier>${env}</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
        <modules>
            <module>webapp-formation</module>
            <module>db-formation</module>
        </modules>
```

But when I'm running `mvn install` the `.pom` files are not generate for my modules. Only my parent is associated with a `.pom` file in my repositories. Thus trying to browse to my module's artifact on Archiva (after running `mvn depoy` of course!) it simply fails. I can browse to the parent but not its children.
So... I need to add the undocumented attribute `generatePom` to my plugin configuration to have the `.pom` files generated *--copied would be a better word actually--* for all my modules. *--I said undocumented attribute because this attribute is documented only for the `install-file` goal which is not the one ran by default. The `install` goal is not expecting that attribute...* 
Of course, if I do not configure my `install` plugin *--so not configuring the classifier--* I have no problem and all `.pom` files are generated properly.

For you guys, is that a normal behavior? Something that you have already seen? Or should I just file a bug?

Thanks,
Olivier.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe as an undocumented attribute is simply wrong, cause the attributes are specific on a goal base which means the given configuration will not change anything, cause the `generatePom` attribute is only valid for `install-file` goal. So you can remove it.

In general such configuration does not make sense, cause if you have different environments you should go a different way. Just removed hte configuration with `<classifier>${env}</classifier>` as well and try to deploy via:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but... I guess you missed what I was explaining. Of course, your solution is working... but not doing what I need to do! Removing the classifier is not an option. You may find a couple of artifacts on maven central which are defining a classifier. For example, you may deploy an artifact compiled with JDK5 compliance and another one for JDK8. Same source, 2 build configurations... 2 classifiers.

Comment: Such things can be handled with a single build no need to do 2 builds.